# Регулярное выражение в Java работает не так, как мне нужно

Tags: java, регулярные-выражения

```
public class Test {
  public static Map<Integer, String> map = new HashMap<Integer, String>();

  static {
    map.put(1, "один");
    map.put(12, "двенадцать");
}

  public static void main(String[] args) {
    String s = "Это стоит 1 бакс, а вот это - 12 .";
    for (Integer integer : map.keySet()) {
        Pattern r = Pattern.compile("\\b" + integer + "\\b");
        Matcher m = r.matcher(s);
        if (m.find()){
            s = s.replace(String.valueOf(integer), map.get(integer));
        }
    }

    System.out.println(s);
    } 
}
```

На https://regex101.com/ если я напишу регулярное выражение \b1\b - найдет только первую единицу перед словом "бакс", в числе 12 - её не найдет.
Но когда я запускаю этот код, то строка меняется на "Это стоит один бакс, а вот это - один2 .", а не на нужное мне "Это стоит один бакс, а вот это - двенадцать ." Почему ? Это особенности обработки регулярных выражений на Java  ? Как записать регулярное выражение, чтобы получить нужный мне результат ?

Answer (score 2):

Это не особенность Java (вот пруф: https://www.regexplanet.com/share/index.html?share=yyyyd274wyr).

Проблема в логике Вашей программы. Вы используете `s = s.replace(String.valueOf(integer), map.get(integer));` для замены числа. Эта инструкция срабатывает или не срабатывает для строки в целом, не принимая во внимание никаких *assertions* в предшествующем регулярном выражении `Pattern.compile("(?<=\\D)" + integer + "(?=\\D)");`.

Вот этот код с `replaceAll` сделает всё:

```java
import java.util.*;
import java.util.regex.*;

public class Test {
  public static Map<Integer, String> map = new HashMap<Integer, String>();

  static {
    map.put(1, "один");
    map.put(12, "двенадцать");
  }

  public static void main(String[] args) {
    String s = "Это стоит 1 бакс, а вот это - 12.";
    for (Integer integer : map.keySet()) {
        s = s.replaceAll("\\b" + integer + "\\b", map.get(integer));
    }
    System.out.println(s);
  } 
}
```

(https://onecompiler.com/java/3w9mntts7)

Answer (score 0):

В вашей программе числа, найденные с помощью регулярного выражения, заменяются уже другим вызовом метода `String#replace`, то есть происходит замена каждого найденного числа *независимо от контекста*, целое это число или нет.

Следует находить и заменять совпадения *непосредственно* при поиске, тогда не будет возникать подобных проблем.

[Пример кода на Java 9+](https://ideone.com/lqufA1):

```
import java.util.*;
import java.util.stream.*;
import java.util.regex.*;
import static java.util.Map.entry; 

class Ideone
{
    public static Map<Integer, String> map = Map.ofEntries(
        entry(1, "один"),
        entry(12, "двенадцать")
    );
    

    public static void main (String[] args) throws java.lang.Exception
    {
        String s = "Это стоит 1 бакс, а вот это - 12 .";
        List<Integer> lst = new ArrayList<>(map.keySet()); // Ключи как список целочисленных значений
        String rx = "\\b(" + String.join("|", lst.stream().map(Object::toString).collect(Collectors.toList())) + ")\\b"; // Создаем регулярное выражение, тут оно выглядит как \b(1|12)\b
        Pattern p1 = Pattern.compile(rx); // Компилируем объект шаблона
        Matcher m = p1.matcher(s);        // Объявляем объект Matcher и передаем в него строку
        String result = m.replaceAll(x -> map.get(Integer.parseInt(x.group())) ); // Заменяем при нахождении сразу
        System.out.println( result ); // Выводим результат на консоль
    }
}
```

Результат: `Это стоит один бакс, а вот это - двенадцать .`

[Код на Java 8](https://wandbox.org/permlink/T62EsUB1iXi0z2rx):

```
import java.util.*;
import java.util.regex.*;

class Wandbox
{
  public static Map<Integer, String> map = new HashMap<Integer, String>();

  static {
    map.put(1, "один");
    map.put(12, "двенадцать");
  }

  public static void main(String[] args)  {
    String s = "Это стоит 1 бакс, а вот это - 12.";
    List<String> lst = new ArrayList<>();
    for (Integer i:map.keySet()) { lst.add(i.toString()); }
    String rx = "\\b(" + String.join("|", lst) + ")\\b";
    StringBuffer result = new StringBuffer();
    Matcher m = Pattern.compile(rx).matcher(s);
    while (m.find()) {
        String val = map.get(Integer.parseInt(m.group()));
        m.appendReplacement(result, val);
    }
    m.appendTail(result);
    System.out.println(result);
  } 
}
```